# Clients pointing their domains to our IP - Concerns & System Longevity

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, dns, cloud, saas

For our SaaS app, we're allowing customers to point their domain name to our server.

The plan right now is to simply hand out one of our AWS elastic IP addresses for them to point their domain to. The elastic IP address would essentially be pointed to a EC2 instance web-server...and maybe a load balancer in time (if traffic demands it!).

The user would specify what their domain is in our app, and we'd be able to resolve the host name coming in as their app.

My concern is the longevity of this solution. This IP cannot change. And we'll certainly be tied to AWS if we go this route.

(Note: Being a 1-2 person startup, standing up a data-center is more than likely no-go, and we hope to use AWS or Azure).

What solutions would make this IP address -> SaaS Web Server concept last in the long run, with flexibility, and as minor of a tie as possible to a cloud provider?

With running the risk of asking "what is the *best* way to do this"...what's the best way to do this, keeping in mind longevity and small opt-in to a cloud provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't point an IP address to a load balancer, so this seems like a very bad idea. You need your own domain/subdomain that clients can point their domains/subdomains to via a CNAME record on their end. Then if the location of your service ever changes you just have to update your domain record and their DNS records will continue to be correct.

Comment: You got here first, so rather than also giving essentially the same answer, I'll back this one. :) And I would add, each client gets their own CNAME target in this "routing" domain, even if not necessary now because of just one back-end.  You *will* regret not doing these things.  And in the case of clients who want their site at the apex of a new vanity domain, not a subdomain... fine, just host their DNS for them, in Route 53.  Totally worth the avoidance of hassle. The objective should be to ensure that your clients *never* have to make a DNS change. Organizing **that** gets unwieldy, fast.